# Deriving wave equation of string without approximation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, string, continuum-mechanics

When deriving the equation for a standing wave of a string, we often approximate that the tension at all points in the wave is constant. but I want to derive the equation without the approximation. I tried to derive it with lagrangian as below:

1. kinetic energy of string with unit length is $\frac{1}{2}λf_t^2$, where $λ$ is the linear density of string, $f$ is the wave function.
2. potential energy of string with unit length is $mg(\frac{dl}{dx}-1)+\frac{1}{2}k(\frac{dl}{dx}-1)^2$, where $dl$ is the small length of stretched string, $m$ is mass of weight, $k$ is constant according to Hooke's law. The first term is the energy generated by the string being stretched by the weight, and The second term is the energy generated by stretching as the shape of the string changes.

3.lagrangian density $L=T-V=\frac{1}{2}λf_t^2-(mg(\frac{dl}{dx}-1)+\frac{1}{2}k(\frac{dl}{dx}-1)^2)$, and $\frac{dl}{dx}=\sqrt{f_x^2+1}$.

4.by euler-lagrange equation $\frac{∂}{∂t}\frac{∂L}{∂f_t}+\frac{∂}{∂x}\frac{∂L}{∂f_x}=\frac{∂L}{∂f}$, I get the equation λ$\frac{∂^2f}{∂t^2}$-$\frac{∂}{∂x}$$\frac{mgf_x}{\sqrt{1+f_x^2}}$ -$k(f_x^2-\frac{f_x}{\sqrt{1+f_x^2}})$, or $λ\frac{∂^2f}{∂t^2}-mg\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}-\frac{3}{2}k\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}f_x^2=0$ with approximation $(1+x)^n=1+nx$ ($x<<1$).
My question is, is this correct? If so, how can I solve this equation?

Comment: if you don't want to assume that the tension is constant, then you will need an equation of state for the tension, i.e., how does it depend on the rest of parameters of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to derive a non linear 1 D wave equation but still assume the motion to be purely transverse: $  \overrightarrow{v}(x,t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}  \overrightarrow{ e_{y} } $. If the tension varies along the string you must include the horizontal component of the velocity: T(x) and T(x+dx) do not cancel out anymore in the x direction.
Your potential energy $ PE=mg \big(\frac{dl}{dx}-1\big)+...$ is false: it is homogeneous to a force (mg).
As a mater of fact, you want to use Lagrangian mechanics to derive your equation but a string has an infinite continuous number of degrees of freedom (parametered by x). You must introduce a potential and kinetic energy density.

Comment: AH..... Hard to make this equation.... I'll work more with this!
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Try to model your problem as an infinite chain of oscillators moving both vertically and horizontally. Or use Newton's laws, it will be simpler.